# Get the variables in another script file

Tags: applescript

I use the "Run Script" command to run a program for another file. But it did not show the results. The result is a variable, how do I get this variable?

Code 1:

```
set xxx to {"ni", "bu", "en"}
set xxx2 to {"hao", "bu", "ni", "bu", "hao"}

repeat with item_number in xxx2
set booleanlist to {}
repeat with item_number_2 in xxx

    if contents of item_number_2 is not contents of item_number then
        set end of booleanlist to true
    end if

    if contents of item_number_2 is contents of item_number then
        set end of booleanlist to false
    end if

end repeat
set booleanlist_number to 0
repeat with booleanlist_number_2 in booleanlist
    if contents of booleanlist_number_2 is true then
        set booleanlist_number to booleanlist_number + 1
    end if
    if contents of booleanlist_number_2 is false then
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

if booleanlist_number = (count item of xxx) then
    set end of xxx to contents of item_number
end if

end repeat
```

Code 2:

```
set xx to run script file "Macintosh HD:Users:mingxianzhao:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:示例:run script and on run:Untitled.scpt" with parameters Character_used_for_the_query
choose from list xx
```

Comment: Show us the code from both scripts, and hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return xxx` to the end of your Code 1 script.

Answer (score 0):

As [@foo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9482466/foo) already stated, you need to add the lines `return xxx` to end of the script "Code 1".

Having looked at "Code 1", it appears as if you are trying to combine the lists `xxx` and `xxx2` into single list, but have the combined list contain only **one** copy of each item, i.e. you want a set of unique items.

This can be done more efficiently and cleanly than your present implementation:

```
set xxx to {"ni", "bu", "en"}
set xxx2 to {"hao", "bu", "ni", "bu", "hao"}

set xxx to xxx & xxx2

return unique(xxx) --> {"ni", "bu", "en", "hao"}


on unique(L)
    local L

    script
        property array : L
        property list : {}
    end script

    tell the result
        repeat with x in its array
            if x is not in its list then set ¬
                end of its list to x's contents
        end repeat

        its list
    end tell
end unique
```